# Yahoo OpenID and Oauth

Tags: oauth, openid, yahoo

My first time here. I am stuck!!! We cannot extract user's Yahoo email address through YahooAPI. To get the Yahoo email, it was suggested that we use OpenID + oAuth.

Does anyone has a sample code for OpenID + oAuth for Yahoo?

I am really stuck here (badly). After countless hours  researching... nothing :( We tried writing it, but it is impossible. We can't do it.

Would really appreciate the help!

Thanks guys. If you are uncomfortable posting it here, please please email me at amp_atp@hotmail.com

Thanks!!

Comment: Please post what you tried.

Comment: Did u get the solution? I am also struck with same problem